# jQuery | Выполнить действия единожды а дальше по выполнению события

Tags: jquery, события

Есть код что при низкой ширине экрана выводит текст в отдельный блок, он выполнялся всегда по загрузке страницы. Я обернул его в "$(window).resize" что-бы он выполнялся каждый раз при изменении размера окна. Но теперь он не выполняется при загрузке страницы. Как решить эту проблему?

```
    $(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(document).width() < 1000) {
        $('#normal-screen-balance-block').hide();
        $('#low-screen-width-balance').show();
        $('#search-end-filter').css('justify-content', 'center');
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать, обернув нужный код в функцию и ее отдельно вызвать

```
function myResize() {
  if ($(document).width() < 1000) {
    $('#normal-screen-balance-block').hide();
    $('#low-screen-width-balance').show();
    $('#search-end-filter').css('justify-content', 'center');
  }
}

$(window).resize(myResize); // Создаем обработчик события
$(document).ready(myResize); // Вызываем единожды при загрузке страницы
```